# CSS: How can I move an object one layer up?

Tags: css

HTML:

```
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
```

CSS:

```
#a {
    float: left;

    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

#b {
    margin-left: 25px;

    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

See my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/mxtdg/;

It seems A is above B, what can I do if I want B to be above A?

Comment: `position:relative` and `z-index` are your friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `position:relative` and `z-index:10` on `#b`, that will do the trick.

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/mxtdg/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/mxtdg/7/)**

Comment: dont you think `position:relative` makes it sideways rather than one on top of other?

Answer (score 0):

You can also float "b"  Then you use the margin to adjust the position.  When their both floating, in this case you don't need to change the z-index, "b" will be on top of "a" because of the order of the HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/mxtdg/12/

Answer (score 0):

its simple you can define **position** and **z-index** value to any **div or id** that you wants above and remember one thing z-index will only work when you will define a position in particular div or id that you wants to above.

see you updated code:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#a {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

#b {
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

or see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/mxtdg/19/